# Only Display Certain List Object Properties in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, data-binding, gridview

I've got a GridView control which is bound to a `List` of custom objects.  The objects have 5 properties, however, I don't want to generate a column in the GridView for all the properties, only for certain ones. I know how to turn off 'AutoGenerateColumns', however, I'm not sure how to then only display certain properties of each object selectively. Does anyone know how this should be done or can provide me with an example of doing this?

---

**EXAMPLE**:

Let's say I have a list like so: `List<Car> cars = new List<Car>`

Each `Car` has a property for `Model`, `Make`, `Year`, `Transmission`, `Color`.

I want my GridView control to be bound to the cars `List`, but only have columns showing `Model`, `Make`, and `Year`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a BoundField or a TemplateField. E.g.

```
<asp :GridView ID=“GridView1″ runat=“server”>
    <columns>
        <asp :BoundField DataField=“ColumnName”
            DataFormatString=“{0:M-dd-yyyy}”
            HtmlEncode=“false”
            HeaderText=“ColumnName” />
        </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

or

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>Make</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                     "Make")%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: No worries - these controls are super powerful so keep reading and trying new things.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a `BindingList<yourObject>`. Essentially it's like a List but makes it easier to bind to as a data source.

Then in your column collection on the front end you would then use the `DataPropertyName` property to display the Public property for each property you want to display. Check out the following article. Hope this helps.

[Binding a GridView to a collection](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection)